# Examination: sonographic evaluation of abdomen and pelvis - report

Tags: liver, kidney, uterus, pelvis-pelvic-bone

Can someone explain the medical terms in this report of ultrasound investigation?

Examination: sonographic evaluation of abdomen and pelvis

- Clinical complaint of right hypochondriac region menorrhagia

Abdominal and pelvic sonography is done using Philips HD - 15 using C5-2 trans - abdominal and L12-3 linear probes.

Opinion:

There is mild (17.1 cm) hepatomegaly with mild grade fatty infiltration noted.

The right kidney shows 'extra - renal ' type pelvis with mild (3.2 X 1.9 cm ) pyelectasis,
Without any caliectasis , favour PUJ obstruction

There is no abnormality detected in gall bladder, pancreas, left kidney, spleen, retroperitoneum and abdominal cavity

There is no mass or free fluid in abdomen and pelvis

There is bulky anteverted uterus, showing a large, sub- serous fibroid at the fundo- anterior uterine wall

Suggest - digital X ray of kub region to visualise any calculus at the right P-U junction

Comment: I slightly edited your question and explained the medical terms in the answer below. Other than that, I cannot evaluate the seriousness of the conditions or suggest further steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Menorrhagia" = excessive menstrual bleeding, possibly associated with uterine fibroids.

"Hepatomegaly" = liver enlargement (mild in this case).

"Fatty infiltration" probably refers to "fatty liver."

"Uterine fibroid" = a benign (non-cancerous) tumor in the uterus.

"PUJ obstruction" (sometimes called "UPJ obstruction") refers to a congenital abnormality that causes blockage of the urine flow in the kidney at the level of pelvico-ureteric junction (between the kidney and ureter). In this case it is in the right kidney.

At the end of the report there is a suggestion to have an X-ray of the right kidney to check for eventual stones or other problems.

You can get much more info if you read something about "PUJ obstruction" (or "UPJ obstruction") and "uterine fibroids." It is then a doctor who can tell how serious these conditions are and what can be done.